# Removal of outliers

Tags: outliers

I work in a chemical laboratory and endeavour to estimate Measurement Uncertainty (MU) from sample retests.  The procedure is well established.   But what I an dealing with is a set of data where some duplicates are quite legitimate and reflect the underlying MU while others are not as the first test of the pair was, for some reason, incorrect.  A double distribution, as it where.

I tend to favour the method of using the '1.5 x IQR' method to eliminate outliers.  I have found that often the trimmed data, when reassessed by the IQR method, has further outliers.  The question is, in my circumstances, is it appropriate to apply this in a second round on the already trimmed data?  Am I approaching the true underlying MU of the test or just fooling myself?

(As I type this I have decided to create a dummy data set of a combined normal distribution and a skewed distribution and see what happens.)

Comment: Welcome! This is a perennial; historically, you could start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce's_criterion). Any method can be justified as long as the data and reasoning are included. Here's one [package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/outliers/outliers.pdf) dedicated to this question. It always helps to have example data and greater context i.e. sample retests. (Sorry, edit to comment was over time limit so new comment)

Comment: I don't understand, from the description, your dataset. Can you post a small sample of it?

Comment: The dataset is variable.  We do several hundred different tests (moisture, ash, fat, protein etc).  Retest results are either good duplicates (normal dist) or skewed due to the first data point being incorrect.  I am trying to filter the good from the bad.  My experiment with dummy data was encouraging.  I know the purist view is to keep outliers but, perennial or not, my scenario is an unusual one.  I think.